# Referencing an adjacent cell from a different sheet based on a minimum formula?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2010, microsoft-excel-2007, google-spreadsheets

Basically, I have dates in A, and weights in B. On sheet 2, A1 I have =min(b) which give me the lowest weight in B.

On sheet2 b1 I want to reference the corresponding date for the minimum weight.

I'm very new at excel so i tried to be as specific as possible! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Enter this on Sheet 2 `B1`

`=VLOOKUP(A1, Sheet1!$A$1:$B$20, 1)`

You should define the last row of `B`, in my example is the last row is 20.

Please remember that this formula will only fetch the **first** date with the minimum weight. If you have 2 dates with the same minimum weight, then it will return the first date, **not** both.

Comment: In Google spreadsheets you do not have to define the last row, the following would be a valid formula too: =VLOOKUP(A1, Sheet1!$A$1:$B, 1)

Comment: VLOOKUP goes from A to B, the OP wants to go from B to A, you need INDEX

Answer (score 1):

You need to use an index formula in B1

=INDEX(Sheet1!A:A,MATCH(MIN(Sheet1!B:B),Sheet1!B:B,0),1)

To break this down, the formula is indexing Sheet1 column A, and is matching the lowest value in column B to get the row number, and is then returning the value from column A in that row.

As Vylix said above, the same applies here. If the minimum value appears more than once, this will look down the list and reference the row of the first one.

Let me know if there are any issues.